# Android - How to read a value from a kotlin flow?

Tags: android, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-stateflow

I have a flow of Episode  from a room database.
I can observe as livedata this flow with no problem.

But I also would like to read the last value from this flow when the user clicks on a button. I tried with first() terminal flow operator but it does not compile. Can you please help or suggest something else?

The non-compiling attempt to read from a flow:

```
bd.buttonNext.setOnClickListener {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        val episode: Episode? = viewModel.episodeFlow().first()           <=== Compile ERROR
        Snackbar.make(bd.root, "episode ${episode?.name}", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

This flow comes from ROOM :

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Episode WHERE id = :id")
fun getEpisode(id: Long): Flow<Episode?>
```

Repository:

```
fun getEpisode(episodeId: Long): Flow<Episode?> = dao.getEpisode(episodeId)
```

View model - The Id comes from a StateFlow :

```
fun episodeFlow(): Flow<Episode?> 
  = episodeIdStateFlow.flatMapLatest { episodeId ->
    repository.getEpisode(episodeId)
  }
```

Compilation error :

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public fun <T> Array<out TypeVariable(T)>.first(): TypeVariable(T) defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <T> Array<out TypeVariable(T)>.first(predicate: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Boolean): TypeVariable(T) defined in kotlin.collections
public fun BooleanArray.first(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun BooleanArray.first(predicate: (Boolean) -> Boolean): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public fun ByteArray.first(): Byte defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun ByteArray.first(predicate: (Byte) -> Boolean): Byte defined in kotlin.collections
public fun CharArray.first(): Char defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun CharArray.first(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): Char defined in kotlin.collections
public fun CharSequence.first(): Char defined in kotlin.text
```

As a "workaround", I saved the episode in an instance variable like this but I would like to avoid doing it if possible :

```
var episode: Episode? = null
...
viewModel.episodeFlow().asLiveData().observe(this) { episode ->
   this.episode = episode
}
...
bd.buttonNext.setOnClickListener {
   Snackbar.make(bd.root, "episode ${episode?.name}", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

=================== UPDATE/SOLUTION 21/01/15 ==================

Solution inspired by beigirad (see his post below) using stateIn :

```
private val _episodeSF  = episodeFlow().stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, null)
val episodeSF: StateFlow<Episode?>
  get() = _episodeSF

fun episodeFlow(): Flow<Episode?> = episodeIdSF.flatMapLatest { episodeId ->
  repository.episodeFlow(episodeId)
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can convert your flow to [StateFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/index.html) by [stateIn](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html) extension and then use its `value` attribute to get the latest value.

```
fun episodeFlow(): StateFlow<Episode?> 
  = episodeIdStateFlow.flatMapLatest { episodeId ->
    repository.getEpisode(episodeId)
  }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Lazily, initialValue)
```

Comment: Thanks beigiard. That's exactly what I need. Please see the update in my question

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've pasted should work since `launch`'s callback already runs inside a coroutine and you can call `suspend` functions from there.

A non blocking solution could be that you use `LiveData` or `StateFlow`. On both you can check for the property `value` which will be `null` if no values were emitted or will contain the last emitted value.

Could you provide more of the `ViewModel` code?

Comment: Actually StateFlow caches values, and replays the previous value...